# Titanium android sdk configuration problem

Tags: android, titanium

I am trying to start developing with Titanium sdk.

I download the IDE and when I give the path of my android sdk (which is running fine in default Eclipse Android Developer suite), it doesn't recognize it.

Please check the video below:

http://screencast.com/t/AQeBORaf

It's weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an empty folder android-7 in $android/platforms...it works after this

EDIT:The above solution doesn't work properly in all cases . He is another alternative which
surely works : if you are using android 2.2 an above( API 8 and above) ,you need to create a symbolic link  between adb file which is in platform-tools(from 2.2 and above) and tools folder. This is because the structure of android SDKs have changed from 2.2 on wards and titanium follows the old structure . So you create a symbolic link of that adb file which was previously in tools folder and has now been transferred to platform-tools folder. This solution is for linux.

$ copy $ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe $ANDROID_SDK/tools

Comment: now android sdk is found, and everything is fine, but when i run the app it gives following error.

[ERROR] Error generating R.java from manifest
[ERROR] W/asset   ( 1628): Asset path F:\android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-7\android.jar is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
[ERROR] ERROR: Asset package include 'F:\android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-7\android.jar' not found.

Comment: i have same problem : [ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  W/asset   ( 5985): Asset path /home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-17/android.jar is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
[ERROR] :  ERROR: Asset package include '/home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-17/android.jar' not found. How did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the path you're specifying might be incomplete. Dont click on the 'android-sdk-windows' folder. Instead try this...**right click** on the 'add-ons' INSIDE that folder.Go to properties and under the 'General' tab there is a 'Location' specified. Copy and paste this location into where your SDK path is needed. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: sorry, it doesnt work, my add-ons folder is also empty, and it is not needed in the standard android developement.

Comment: That's right- you don't need the add-ons folder but you need the location of your sdk...The add-ons is inside the sdk.That's why I thought if you use the location of add-ons you'll get the path to your sdk. Good luck anyhow! :)